# What are the exact requirements for the 'Perform a near crash' objective in the 'That's Not in the Script!' Gangstas in Space DLC mission?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

One of the objectives in the '[That's Not in the Script!](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/That%27s_Not_in_the_Script!)' Gangstas in Space DLC mission is to 'Perform a near crash' with the 'Aegean' ship.

In my first playthrough of this mission part, I failed it several times as I always destroy my ship before meeting the 'near crash' requirements, even though I have performed multiple near crashes (like shown in the screenshot below). I have finished the mission eventually, but I still do not know what are the exact requirements to finish this mission part.

**How many or how long do my 'near crashes' have to be for this mission?**

[image: 'That's Not in the Script!' Gangstas in Space DLC mission objective: 'Perform a near crash]

Comment: I suspect it may be a matter of time (delay) rather than distance or quantity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that this objective gets met very quickly with around 40m (say 130ft; SRTT sets measures to metric if your region settings in Windows says it should) of near crash but from your screenshot, it looks like you've changed the flight mode to plane instead of hover. I keep it on hover.

Try this; leave your ship on hover, and fly close to a building. The near crash indicator should appear, so just stop. I suspect that NiteCyper is right insofar as the trigger is time in a near crash setting, and that's more likely to happen if you're just hovering in the zone that triggers the near crash indicator.

In one pass through this mission, I got 2 different near crash indicators and the second one was shorter, but seemed to trigger the completion of the objective. If that is any indication, there is probably a separate counter that is measuring *cumulative* near crash time, rather than a given distance. Certainly my 'parking' near a building would also lend some support to that hypothesis.